# Node v11 throws with spread operator

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I'm trying to build an electron app and I'm using [electron-unhandled](https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-unhandled)
 in it, but when running my app it throws

```
App threw an error during load C:\CLC\VIDA\Web\Comun\ypalma\todoapp\node_modules\electron-unhandled\index.js:74
                ...options,
                ^^^ SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:528:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\CLC\VIDA\Web\Comun\ypalma\todoapp\index.js:3:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
```

The line of the reference has this code

```
options = {
    ...options,
    ...inputOptions
};
```

Now, the weird thing is that I'm using node v11.5.0 which has support for spread operator, so I'm stuck with this. So, the question is, how can I make this work without compilling to es5? I mean, node is supposed to handle this syntax right?

In case it helps, my electron version is v5.0.1 and I'm working with windows 10.

Comment: Node v11 (even v11.0.0) supports all of the meanings of `...`. So if you're really using Node v11 and it's giving you a syntax error pointing to `...`, that `...` is a syntax error. It sounds like you might *not* be using Node v11, though. Looking at Line 74 of your off-site link (questions shouldn't rely on off-site links), it's valid property spread (ES2018+).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that's what I thought too, but in the source on that github page it looks OK to me. Also interestingly that's the first spread syntax in that module.

Comment: @Pointy - Yeah, I just edited that comment. If they're getting that error with that code, they aren't using Node v11.

Comment: I am using node 11, I have no version manager so this is my only node version installed. I know that spread operator are supported since v8.x.x that's why I think it's weird

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I've edited to add the code that throws. Also double checked my node version and updated to 12. Still the same error.

Comment: @YerkoPalma - I think you must be mistaken about the version of the JavaScript engine running the code where you're getting the error. Remember that electron has two parts, effectively it's both a client and a server. The only explanation I can think of is that what you think is Node v11 (or v12) is (say) the server, but the client half is an older version and that's what's running the code with the property read. (Or of course, the other way around.) Bottom line is that Node v11/v12 is **not** throwing a syntax error for that code.

Comment: You can find out what version is running that code by using exactly the same mechanism to call a script that does `console.log(process.version)`. According to [the docs](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/process), both the Main and Renderer processes support `process`. (You can also see what version of V8 is being used via `console.log(process.versions.v8)`; anything from about 6.2 onward has property spread.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder after checking my process version numbers at runtime, I get the following v8 5.3.332.47; node 6.5.0; electron 1.4.13. So, for some reason this is running a completly different version at runtime than what I've installed. So no clue of what is going on.

Comment: At least now you know what the problem is. :-) (In general terms, that is.)

Comment: Yeah, I think I will close this soon, hopefully with a complete explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after @T.J.Crowder advises, I found that my electron app was running a different version of node and electron. The electron version installed was `^5.0.1`, but the issue was that I also have `electron-prebuilt` installed, which has node version `6.0.5` and electron version `1.4.13`. 
So this module overrides my node and electron versions. Simply uninstalling it and reinstalling electron did the trick.